# Can you call qsort on section of an array/matrix (row major order)?

Tags: c, matrix, pthreads, qsort, row-major-order

Can you call qsort on section of an array or matrix in row major order?

I would like to call qsort on separate parts of an array within pthreads, is this thread safe and okay to do?

I am working on separating the given array or matrix by the amount of threads or cores given as a global variable `n_threads` and then calling qsort on each section in the same arrays memory. I want to use a start value and a total values to get the start and end index of the qsort function.

```
// @Return - returns a comparison function for quicksort
int cmp_func (const void * a, const void * b) {
    return ( *(float*)a - *(float*)b );
}

// struct used for passing arguments from merge_sort to merge_sort recursively
typedef struct {
    float* m;
    size_t t_id;
} t_arg_sort;

// Initalises a new sorted matrix within threads.
static void* pthread_sorted(void* arg) {
    t_arg_sorted* t_arg = (t_arg_sorted*) arg;
    const size_t start = t_arg->t_id * (n_elements/n_threads);
    qsort(t_arg->r + start, (n_elements/n_threads), sizeof(float), cmp_func);
    return NULL;
}

// Sorts matrix
float* sorted(const float* matrix) {
    float* new_matrix = new_matrix();

    t_arg_sort thread_args[n_threads];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) {
        thread_args[i] = (t_arg_sort) {
            .m = new_matrix,
            .t_id = i
        };
    }

    // create threads to sort matrix
    pthread_t threads[n_threads];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) {
        if(pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, pthread_reversed, thread_args + i) != 0) {
            perror("Create thread failed!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // join threads after all coordinates have been initialised
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) != 0) {
            perror("Join thread failed!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    qsort(new_matrix, g_elements, sizeof(float), cmp_func);

    return new_matrix;
}
```

Comment: If you give each thread a non-overlapping section of a big array to sort, you can safely use `qsort()` to sort the sections.  But you'll need to pass different information from what you're currently passing — you'll need a start element pointer and a number of elements to sort, and you'll partition the array in the calling code (divide it up into pieces).  Once you've done that, you have to merge the results, which is where life gets tricky — you can merge into a copy of the space in the original array easily enough, but you can't readily merge into the segment-sorted original array.

Comment: Your cmp_func will treat 0.5 and 0.6 as equal. Also, it makes no sense to sort sections of an array and then call `qsort` on the entire array.

Comment: @n.m. I completed it and it does give better efficiency than just calling qsort on the entire array though I agree it is highly redundant however is a good exercise for accessing separate parts of an array. May I ask why the cmp_func with treat 0.5 and 0.6 as equal?

Comment: "it does give better efficiency" With your invalid comparison function, maybe. In my experiments it doesn't. "why the cmp_func with treat 0.5 and 0.6 as equal" Because 0.6-0.5 gives 0.1 which gets converted to an `int` and truncated to 0.